# Facebook Canvas Application in Mobile Native App doesn't fit screen

Tags: css, facebook, mobile, web-applications, iframe

I have a fluid layout application optimized for mobile, the page does fit and render perfectly on mobile screens.

This application is accessible via facebook as Canvas Application. I set Fluid measures for the iframe in the facebook app settings.

Everything's OK on desktop (or mobile browser).
But on mobile native app, facebook, doesnt set the proper measures on iframe, no matter what it renders like the screen is 768px, also screen.width from inside the iframe says 768. 
If i open my app outside fb in a mobile browser the screen.width is correctly set on 384px.

I haven't set the app as "Mobile App" because in that case i am redirected outside fb.
So i only have a Canvas App set.

I tried the various

```
FB.Canvas.setSize();
FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: X, height: Y });
FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
```

None of it works inside FB App.
Do you have any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Canvas APP on android cannot be opened inside Facebook chrome, instead they must redirect elsewhere.
On iphone the flow is the same with the exception of opening the canvas app from Facebook website inside the browser.
In any case the mobile layout is not supported by canvas app inside facebook.